# Reverse binding in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have two input boxes. Whatever typed in first input box should show in second, it is easy. But, If I typed something in second input box and try to display in first it doesn't work.

Here is code.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="first" value={{second}}>
  <input type="text" value={{first}} ng-model="second">
</div>
```

Is it not allowed in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have two input boxes share the same value is what you want , then assigning the the same scope variable for the both the ng-model would also work .

```
<div ng-app="">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.sameName">
  <input type="text" ng-model="form.sameName">
</div>
```

And it is adviced to use dot notation for the ng-model variables .

Comment: What if I have four input boxes such that first two with same value binding and other two with same value binding. Then what will be in "ng-model" for those input boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You are closer, use the same ng-model for both the inputs,

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="data">
 <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data">
<br>
```

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
 myApp.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    <br>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @WeAreRight because you have two different models

Comment: What about solution provided below by @32theeths. It looks somewhat easy to remember.

Comment: It's the same solution, using the same variable across two models

Comment: What if I have four input boxes such that first two with same value binding and other two with same value binding. Then what will be in "ng-model" for those input boxes.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by having that? it depends on your requirement

Comment: Actually there are two sections within same form. Fields like 'name', 'address','city' etc. are repeated in both. I don't want user to type in both sections. And what ever he types should reflected to its corresponding twin input boxes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138384/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-weareright).